# Selecting data for a specific coordinate, openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

**Firstly - piece of my data:**

[image: Data]

**I need to plot a line chart with years on the X axis and people's height on the Y axis:**[image: expected chart]

**But I'm getting it:**
[image: Incorrect result]

**For plotting chart I using code below**

```
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference
chart = LineChart()
chart.title='Average height'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Height'
chart.x_axis.title = 'Year'


values = Reference(working_sheet, min_col = 7, min_row = 1, max_col=9, max_row = 102)
chart.add_data(values, titles_from_data=True)
working_sheet.add_chart(chart, 'K2')
```

**So I need to know how I can select data for a specific coordinate using openpyxl**

Comment: You need to remove the year from the data series.

Comment: @CharlieClark , I need the year as axis. Else I will get chart with heights on Y axis and numbers of rows on X axis

Comment: Currently you're adding the dates as a data series. The openpyxl documentation includes an example using a date axis, why don't you follow that?

Comment: Because I need only year as axis and I can't just transform it to "date" type.